# How to copy data streaming between 2 aws profiles

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, scripting, copy

I am trying to copy 20Tb of data between 2 S3 buckets in 2 different aws accounts, tried this command and it seems that it's getting only the folder or the file inside, and i want to copy the whole bucket data.

```
aws --profile <dev> s3 cp s3://bucket/path - | aws --profile <prod> s3 cp - s3://bucket/path
```

Comment: It's generally best to setup an [IAM role that has access to both buckets](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/copy-s3-objects-account/), then copy data across so you can copy to/from S3 directly.

Comment: yes it is best practice, but they want it done otherwise or maybe they are testing me :D,

Comment: Then you pretty much either need to sync the data locally to disk, then back up, or write a custom script.  AWS's CLI has no mode to output all of the files in a bucket in a way it can consume to write to a bucket.

Answer (score 0):

20 TB of data is rather big and can take a LONG TIME to download and upload. (Even copying 1Tb of data between folders on your own computer takes a long time, but doing it across the Internet can take a ridiculously long time!)

As an example, at a 1Gbps transfer speed, 20TB of data would take 44 hours to transfer. And since you are wanting to download & upload, it will take *twice* that time. (They might well be 'testing' you!)

Instead, it would make much more sense to use the capabilities of Amazon S3 to **copy files directly between buckets** without downloading & uploading the content. You can do this with the `aws s3 sync` command.

You mention that the source and destination are in two different AWS Accounts. There are therefore two ways you can perform the copy:

**'Pull' method**

This is where you use credentials from the **destination** account and 'pull' the objects from the source account:

- The owner of the **source bucket** would need to **add a bucket policy** that permits Read access for the IAM credentials being used

**'Push' method**

This is where you use credentials from the **source** account and 'push' the data to the destination account:

- The owner of the **destination bucket** would need to **add a bucket policy** that permits Write access for the IAM credentials being used
- When copying the objects, specify `--acl bucket-owner-full-control` so that object ownership is transferred to the destination account (Only required when writing to a different AWS Account)

Copying 20TB of data will still take some time, but the AWS CLI will send the Copy commands in parallel, greatly speeding the process. All data transfer happens within Amazon S3, without downloading any data to your computer.

Comment: Great read, thanks for that, so it will be the pull method to resolve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to possibly do it is to mount the s3 bucket directly on the instance and copy the files from there. Works for a small amount of data. But for 20tb, it’s not optimal.